# Is it possible to make the background of a button transparent?

Tags: android, image

I have a button like so...

[image]

Sorry if it looks dark but as you can see, I have set the height and width to wrap content but the scaletype is not fitxy so there is still "button excess" if you will.

Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: use an `ImageButton` and set the background of it to transparent like this :  `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: actually this the problem of image when you use ImageButton as src also you will get the transparent image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an `ImageButton` and set the background of it to transparent like this : `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_login" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can used ImageButton. Do it in your xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonSettings"
    android:src="@drawable/tabbar_icon"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

or programmatically. this is the simple only you have to set background color as transparent

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 3):

//yes you can do it thru `android:alpha` in xml

//add this below line in your button properties and change your alpha level as what you want

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

Answer (score 1):

use `#0000` (only four zeros otherwise it will be considered as black) this is the color code for transparent. You can use it directly but I recommend you to define a color in color.xml so you can enjoy re-usefullness of the code.

Comment: To be precise: it would be considered as **black** in these cases: #000, #f000, #000000 and #ff000000

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to the button tag

```
<button
android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```